# Getting error "Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to import tensorflow an keras with following code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
```

I am getting the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     63   try:
---> 64     from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     65   # This try catch logic is because there is no bazel equivalent for py_extension.

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.



ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
```

Please help me with useful solutions. I have tried to solve with updates pip, python, and tensorflow versions. Still it is not working.

Comment: The error says "See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors", you should go to that webpage and look up solutions, this is a very common problem, the most likely solution is that you are missing some VS C++ redistributable libraries.

Comment: Thanks, first I was struggling to install that. Finally, it worked.

Comment: Dr. Snoopy this solution fix my problem